# iPhone as a Midi Controller

Tags: iphone, midi, bonjour

I'm attempting to create an application for my iPhone to enable the phone to act as a hardware interface to control software on my computer through midi mapping. For example to assign cue buttons in software such as Ableton/Traktor onto a GUI interface controlled on the Phone.

I am aware that previous versions of this have been created, such as the ITM Matrix http://www.itouchmidi.com/?q=node/5. I have been using this application but I have some variations i wish to implement so figured the best way to learn would be to start from scratch. Though my programming skills are limited I'm hoping this task shouldn't be too difficult and would appreciate any advice in how best to get this up and running.

Cheers

Mike

Comment: This would not be the easiest task if your programming skills are limited, and this question is way too broad to expect a good answer.  But, luckily for you, there's already an app that will probably do what you need — check out [TouchOSC](http://hexler.net/software/touchosc) with [LiveControl](http://liine.net/livecontrol/).

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have a difficult time with little programming experience. But here is the documentation on the [Core MIDI Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CACoreMIDIRef/_index.html) in iOS which you are going to need.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write my own [iPhone MIDI Controller app](http://www.shakemidi.com) too.

What really helped the most was this five part blog post series that really helped to understand [how Core MIDI works on iOS](http://syntheticbits.com/blog/?p=508).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of open source code called PGMidi (http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2011/02/pgmidi-updated.html) that is a good example of sending and receiving midi on iOS using core midi. He has a working example that you could try tinkering with.